# Get parent directory of MSBuildProjectDirectory

Tags: msbuild, directory, parent, targets

I have solution with projects. Also I have in solution directory folder with msbuild files.

In msbuild file I have next code :

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Build Directories">
   <RootPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)'))</RootPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <MSBuildProjectInfrastructure Include="$(RootPath)MyApp.Services.Infrastructure.sln">
   <AdditionalProperties>Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);</AdditionalProperties>
   </MSBuildProjectInfrastructure>
 </ItemGroup>
```

Which works badly, as I need to go in parent directory to find `MyApp.Services.Infrastructure.sln`

Structure :

```
SolutionFolder

 -- MsBuildsFolder

 -- ProjectFile
```

---

Here is [quite similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418874/how-can-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-msbuild-file), but doesn't resolve my issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the parent folder, you can let MSBuild determine the location of known file in that folder by means of the built in property function [GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions#msbuild-getdirectorynameoffileabove):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootPath>$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildThisFileDirectory), MyApp.Services.Infrastructure.sln))</RootPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```